# File is not under 'rootDir'.rootDir' is expected to contain all source files

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am using Visual Studio Code.I got this error while building components.The error is coming from the new Typescript file i have written,the code seems to be good.As its propreitory i cannot put it here.Can you guys tell me the possibilities,why i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You are be in the root directory of your project where you are running ng commands.....you must have package.json or other files in the directory where you are running ng commands

Comment: Yeah i have it.          error TS6059: File '/Users/ram/Documents/********/git/sf-ng-libraries/********/projects/******/sf-model/src/lib/core/addresses/Address.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/Users/ram/Documents/**********/git/sf-ng-libraries/sf-ng-libraries/projects/********/sf-components/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

Comment: It means there are other .ts files that are not placed into your "rootDir". Check your rootDir in tsconfig.json. Try to remove them or place them all into the rootDir.